# Error: Data initializer is not allowed here?

Tags: c++

code:

```
struct example
{
    int a = 0;   // line 3
    example()
    {}
};
```

I am gettting data initializer is not allowed here error at  Line 3

How to solve this?

Comment: Use C++11 or newer and it should be fine.

Comment: That is not a declaration, it is an initialization. `struct example ex  = { .a = 0.};` And in case a is meant to be a constant, use enum.

Comment: @wired Designated initializers didn't appear until C++20 and you don't need `struct` to instantiate a `class`. Initializing an `int` with a `double` also seems odd.

Comment: You may need to explain that point more, @wired . I'm not sure where you're going with it and as worded, I read it as incorrect.

Comment: How to set the Standard used by [Visual Studio Compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-160). How to set it with G++ and related compilers: Add `-std=<Standard>`. Eg `-std=c++11`

Comment: @Ted - the points a typo (was not meant to be a double). Thanks for your input regarding C++ Version, that I was not aware of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `C++` prior to C++11 standard, you cannot initialize value where you declare it, you have to do it with constructor:

```
struct example
{
//    int a = 0; NOT ALLOWED
    int a;
    example() : a (0) {} // preferred way
/*  NOT PREFERRED WAY
    example() {
        a = 0;
    }
*/
}
```

EDIT:
Thank to [@user4581301](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4581301/user4581301) for the comments:

[Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) is initialization list

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-lists) is why is initialization list preferred

Answer (score 1):

> How to solve this?

A few options:

- Upgrade to C++11 (or later), where default member initialisers are were introduced to the language.
- Or don't use default member initialisers. You can either:

  - Initialise in the member initialisation list of the constructor
  - Or don't use a constructor and use aggregate initialisation instead.